# Definition of a vector and a scalar

Tags: vector-spaces

A simple introduction of vectors given in pre-high school classes (in Physics usually) involves considering them as objects having a magnitude and a direction as opposed to scalars which just have a magnitude.

A more rigorous mathematical definition used for defining a vector space is as follows:

> A vector space over a field F is a set V together with two operations that satisfy the eight axioms listed below. In the following, V × V denotes the Cartesian product of V with itself, and → denotes a mapping from one set to another.

where the two operations are the usual addition and scalar multiplication operations while the 'eight' axioms are well-known.

Now, where in the above definition the distinction between a scalar and a vector comes out?

Particularly, if the above-defined set has members which have no 'pointy' arrows (or directions) then also that it fits the above definition.

Also, in Physics vectors are sometimes taught as objects whose components transform according to a transformation rule. How is this feature a consequence of the above definition?

I feel that this has to do with how the addition operation is defined above (for a vector space it should be the parallelogram addition and not a simple scalae addition) but I am not sure since the above definition just mentions "addition" and not a particularly special type of addition like vector addition.

In short, how does the definition of a vector space above establish a clear distinction between vectors and scalars?

Comment: "*How does the definition of a vector space above establish a clear distinction between vectors and scalars?*"  The vectors are the elements of $V$ while the scalars are the elements of $\Bbb F$.  Now... it may so happen that the sets $V$ and $\Bbb F$ are equal... in which case... *there is no distinction* because *there doesn't need to be*.

Comment: "*The above definition just mentions 'addition' and not a particularly special type of addition like vector addition*"  The addition used is whatever the addition is that makes sense for the set $V$.  Different sets may have different "additions" defined and may be as abstract as one wishes... so long as it satisfies the necessary axioms and definitions to be named as such.  For instance the "addition" having an "additive identity"... a "zero" if you will... such that if you were to "add" a vector $v$ by "zero" then the result would again be $v$... whatever "add" and "zero" made sense.

Comment: I would find it hard to answer this question without writing ... well ... a book(let) of some sort. Which would need to give a lot of examples, and also build, sort of, a mathematician's mindset with respect to vector spaces. E.g. let's say $V$ is a vector space, with the operations as you noted. The elements of $V$ can be called "vectors" but only in reference to that vector space. To *be* a vector, in mathematics, is not a *property* of an object/element of a set, it is more a *role* that this element plays with all the other elements and with the given operations, in a given vector space.

Comment: So, if in geometry you take ordered pairs $(A,B)$ of points, and then make some of them equivalent: $(A, B)\sim(C,D)$ if and only if there is a translation that maps $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $D$ ... and you then make the *quotient set* (set of mutually equivalent subsets) which you call $\vec{AB}$, and then you define addition and scalar (real number) multiplication "the ordinary way" - you get *one example* of a vector space where the conjugacy classes of pairs of points are playing the role of "vectors".

Comment: On the other hand, you can have a purely abstract vector space, let's say $V=\{\bigcirc, \square\}$ and you define $\begin{array}{c|cc}+&\bigcirc&\square\\\hline\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\square\\\square&\square&\bigcirc\end{array}$ and $\begin{array}{c|cc}\cdot&\bigcirc&\square\\\hline\bigcirc&\bigcirc&\bigcirc\\\square&\bigcirc&\square\end{array}$ - you get a very simple vector space where elements of $V$ play a role of both vectors and scalars, which is however very remotely related to anything physical. (Or is it?)

Comment: I guess the problem with terminology here is that in physics you assume that a physical quantity *is* a scalar or a vector, where really the wording should be whether the physical quantity is *best described*, mathematically, using ordinary numbers (real or complex) - or using vectors. You may then learn that the best description is often *neither*, and is instead one of: *a function* (a scalar field), *a function taking values on tangent space on a manifold* (a vector field), and let me not even start about tensors.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  "the physical quantity is best described, mathematically, using ordinary numbers (real or complex) - or using vectors" Right, I understand this. The problem still pertains though since both the *descriptions* are clearly different in the sense that one has a direction associated with it but the other does not. This distinction should come out from the definition of the Vector Space but it doesn't (I can't see it). In short, consider the following scenario: (cont'd)

Comment: You come across a Physical quantity that is best described by a mathematical object which has a magnitude and a direction. You then take elements of the space  *V* as defined above and equipped with addition being the vector addition and everything works fine. Now, let's say you come across a physical quantity (think temperature) which requires only the magntiude (a scalar field) for it's complete description. You can *still* take elements from space *V* but now with addition being normal scalar addition. So, does it now make sense to call the elements in the former case as *vectors* and..

Comment: the space as a *vector space*? Since clearly scalars also can belong to *V* as a space built from them also satisfies the definition. The problem is that scalars and vectors are considered to be two different mathematical objects and it is clear that they are (obviously right?) but nowhere from the definition can a person know this.

Comment: A person having no prior knowledge of vectors, scalars, etc and of physical quantities of this world when given this definition would not be able to deduce the difference between a scalar and a vector (as far as I can see) and then that seems like a poor definition. Also, in the example of the abstract vector space you gave above, you correctly noted that it is both scalar and a vector according to the mathematical definition but it doesn't transform on coordinate change etc so I mean if I had seen it just with the background of Physics I wouldn't have considered them vectors.

Comment: Also, this definition alone *does not* even differentiate between a vector field and a scalar field since all fields are vector spaces over some field right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128797/discussion-between-lost-and-stinking-bishop).